# Where to put a text file in Grails, and how to get the path

Tags: java, file, grails, inputstream

I need to read in a .txt file into a groovy class in order to interrogate it line by line.  But I am not sure what folder I put it into in my grails app, and how to get the path to it?

So far I have tried placing it under `src` and also in a new folder `web-app/txt`

and I have tried the the following to read it in

```
fileIn = new File('/lexicon.txt').text
```

and

```
fileIn = new File('txt/lexicon.txt').text
```

to no avail.

Any body have any pointers?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Grails is a Java Web Application, so it will be compiled into a sigle file `.war`, with all files/classes/etc inside. Most Web containers do unpack `war`, but there are no any guaranteee, so it's not a good idea to use `File` to access this file as a file.

Btw, you can place your file into `grails-app/conf`, at this case it will be placed into `classpath`, and you'll be able to access it by using:

```
InputStream lexicon = this.class.classLoader.getResourceAsStream('lexicon.txt')
```

You could also put this file into a subdirectory, like `grails-app/conf/data` and load it as `***.getResourceAsStream('data/lexicon.txt')`

Comment: IMO put misc. files under conf directory it's not a perfect idea.

Comment: it's not just a "misc. file", it's a configuration artifact most likely

Comment: If files are put into src/main/resources then they can be accessed exactly the same way as the above.  

String fileNameAndPath = this.class.classLoader.getResource("actualFileName.txt").getFile()

Comment: It works with grails v3.3.6, to use it as json you need to add: `myFile.getText()`then parse it: `JSON.parse(myFileAsText)`.

Answer (score 22):

You can put your file under web-app/

Example:

```
web-app/lexicon.txt
```

And then in your controller or service use grailsApplication:

```
class MyService {
    def grailsApplication
    public myMethod() {
        File myFile = grailsApplication.mainContext.getResource("lexicon.txt").file
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 13):

You can use Spring's resource loading to access the file.  With this method you can access the file from a Spring bean, which means Grails can autowire the resource in to its artifacts.

*See below for the following steps examples*

1. Place the file in `grails-app/conf/`.
2. Make a resource holder class in `src/groovy`
3. Add the resource holder as a Spring bean in `grails-app/spring/resources.groovy`
4. Then autowire and use the resource wherever you need it

Step 2:

```
package resource

import org.springframework.core.io.Resource

class ResourceHolder {
    Resource lexicon
}
```

Step 3:

```
beans = {
    lexiconHolder(resource.ResourceHolder) {
        lexicon = 'classpath:lexicon.txt'
    }
}
```

Step 4:

```
class AnyGrailsService {
    def lexiconHolder

    void aMethodUsingTheLexicon() {
        File lexicon = lexiconHolder.lexicon.file

        /* Do stuff with the lexicon */
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

In Grails 2, you can use the Grails Resource Locator

```
class MyService {
    def grailsResourceLocator

    myMethod() {
        def fileIn = grailsResourceLocator.findResourceForURI('/txt/lexicon.txt').file
    }
}
```

Handy tip: to mock this in Spock, use GroovyPageStaticResourceLoader

```
@TestFor(MyService)
class MyServiceSpec extends Specification {
    def setup() {
        service.grailsResourceLocator = Mock(GroovyPageStaticResourceLocator)
    }
}
```