# Reading file from Workspace in Jenkins with Groovy script

Tags: groovy, jenkins

I want to add a Build step with the Groovy plugin to read a file and trigger a build fail depending on the content of the file.

How can I inject the workspace file path in the groovy plugin ?

```
myFileDirectory = // Get workspace filepath here ???
myFileName = "output.log"
myFile = new File(myFileDirectory + myFileName)

lastLine = myFile.readLines().get(myFile.readLines().size().toInteger() - 1)
if (lastLine ==~ /.Fatal Error.*/ ){
    println "Fatal error found"
    System.exit(1)
} else{
   println "nothing to see here"
}
```

Comment: Jenkins can fail itself based on e.g. test results. What exactly You want achieve? Maybe there's a plugin for it already. Instead of passing a filename You can implement file search.

Comment: I have an external program (exe) that I'm calling to generate an executable, it also generate a log file. I want to look in that log file and fail the build if [Fatal Error] is found.

Comment: Well, ok. I guess this log has some name that can be easily recognized. If so, find this file for given path and check the content.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Based on your comments, you would be better off with **[Text-finder](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Text-finder+Plugin)** plugin.

It allows to search file(s), as well as console, for a regular expression and then set the build either `unstable` or `failed` if found.

As for the Groovy, you can use the following to access `${WORKSPACE}` environment variable:
`def workspace = manager.build.getEnvVars()["WORKSPACE"]`

Comment: #groovyNoob here.
where can manager.bulid.getEnvVars be imported?

Comment: Note that in system Groovy script step you just do `def workspace = build.getEnvVars()["WORKSPACE"]`. The `build` variable should be availble without any imports. So then you can read a file like so: `def svnVersion = new File(workspace, 'artifacts/svn-revision').text;`

Answer (score 89):

I realize this question was about creating a plugin, but since the new Jenkins 2 Pipeline builds use Groovy, I found myself here while trying to figure out how to read a file from a workspace in a Pipeline build. So maybe I can help someone like me out in the future.

Turns out it's very easy, there is a [readfile](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-readfile-code-read-file-from-workspace) step, and I should have rtfm:

```
env.WORKSPACE = pwd()
def version = readFile "${env.WORKSPACE}/version.txt"
```

Comment: Can you iterate through the object, after reading it? I am unable to do.. And Jenkins isn't throwing an error at the same time.. tried od debugging silly stuff.. pheww!

Comment: the output is a String so you can parse that and split on \n if you want to look at it line by line

Comment: There is no need to call pwd as using relative paths work just fine. Example : readfile("./version.txt")

Comment: I want to access/read all txt files (including sub dir of workspace as well) using groovy postbuild. How to do that?

Answer (score 30):

If you are trying to read a file from the workspace during a pipeline build step, there's a method for that:

```
readFile('name-of-file.groovy')
```

For reference, see https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#readfile-read-file-from-workspace.

Comment: actually the provided link tells about `readFile()` (I didn't find any `readFileFrom Workspace()` ) - but thanks anyway, because readFile() solved my problem!

Answer (score 6):

May this help to someone if they have the same requirement.

This will read a file that contains the Jenkins Job name and run them iteratively from one single job.

Please change below code accordingly in your Jenkins.

```html
pipeline {
   agent any

   stages {
      stage('Hello') {
         steps {
             script{
            git branch: 'Your Branch name', credentialsId: 'Your crendiatails', url: ' Your BitBucket Repo URL '

##To read file from workspace which will contain the Jenkins Job Name ###
           
     def filePath = readFile "${WORKSPACE}/ Your File Location"                   

##To read file line by line ###
 
     def lines = filePath.readLines() 
      
##To iterate and run Jenkins Jobs one by one ####

                    for (line in lines) {                                            
                      build(job: "$line/branchName",
                        parameters:
                        [string(name: 'vertical', value: "${params.vert}"),
                        string(name: 'environment', value: "${params.env}"),
                        string(name: 'branch', value: "${params.branch}"),
                        string(name: 'project', value: "${params.project}")
                        ]
                    )
                        }  
                                       }
                    
         }
         }
      }
   }
```

Comment: hey, how to read two files(one from workspace and other file from console output which i saved in variable) line by line and compare the lines,if it matches then print if not matches then exit 1

Answer (score 5):

Although this question is only related to finding directory path ($WORKSPACE) however I had a requirement to **read the file from workspace and parse it into JSON object** to read sonar issues ( ignore minor/notes issues )

Might help someone, this is how I did it-
from [readFile](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#readfile-read-file-from-workspace)

```
jsonParse(readFile('xyz.json'))
```

and jsonParse method-

```
@NonCPS
def jsonParse(text) {
        return new groovy.json.JsonSlurperClassic().parseText(text);
}
```

This will also require script approval in ManageJenkins-> In-process script approval

Comment: FWIW there is now a `readJSON` function available from _Jenkins_ in addition to `readFile`.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the Groovy (Postbuild) plugin installed, I think it's a valid desire to get this done with (generic) Groovy instead of installing a (specialized) plugin.

That said, you can get the workspace using `manager.build.workspace.getRemote()`. Don't forget to add `File.separator` between path and file name.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a different post [Read .txt file from workspace groovy script in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48401363/read-txt-file-from-workspace-groovy-script-in-jenkins) I was struggling to make it work for the pom modules for a file in the workspace, in the 
Extended Choice Parameter. Here is my solution with the printlns:

```
import groovy.util.XmlSlurper
import java.util.Map
import jenkins.*
import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.*
import hudson.model.*    

try{
//get Jenkins instance
    def jenkins = Jenkins.instance
//get job Item
    def item = jenkins.getItemByFullName("The_JOB_NAME")
    println item
// get workspacePath for the job Item
    def workspacePath = jenkins.getWorkspaceFor (item)
    println workspacePath

    def file = new File(workspacePath.toString()+"\\pom.xml")
    def pomFile = new XmlSlurper().parse(file)
    def pomModules = pomFile.modules.children().join(",")
    return pomModules
} catch (Exception ex){
    println ex.message
}
```