# Jenkins Read a Specific Line of a File in Jenkinsfile with Groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am trying to read a specific line of an `html` file in a Jenkins `stage` with `Groovy` and save its contents to an environment variable. The problem is, `File` and `readLines()` are not allowed.

I am able to load a file with

```
env.WORKSPACE = pwd()
def file = readFile "${env.WORKSPACE}/file.html"
```

[Provided in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38679858/5047630)

But how can I access instantly to the contents of line `n`? I am using `Jenkins 2.32`

Comment: would it be sufficient to grep for something on the line you want instead of referencing it via line number?

Comment: Does `file.split(System.getProperty("line.separator"))[n]` do it?

Comment: Grep is not sufficient as there are many lines with identical boilerplate. What I want to get out of the file is a percentage number. I'll test the above tomorrow.

Comment: fyi this is a jenkins bug: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-46988

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I Tried the suggestion of tim_yates from the comments but `System` was also forbidden. What ultimately worked for me was just changing `System.getProperty("line.separator")` to new line character `"\n"`.

So the full answer was in its simplicity:

```
file.split("\n")[n]
```

Comment: You might want to add a `.trim()` on that just in case there's a Windows `\r` in there as well.

Comment: Instead of `.trim()` you can do `file.split("\r?\n")[n]` which splits on either `\n` or `\r\n`.

Answer (score 12):

Just going to leave documented here, but you can also use readLines().

```
def file = readFile location
def lines = file.readLines()
```

[From this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44135207/2069549)

Comment: The question states `The problem is, File and readLines() are not allowed.`