# Jenkins pipeline get value from JS file

Tags: jenkins

I have JS file in my project with config:

```
export default {
  key: "water",
  title: "Shop",
  icon: "shop-icon",
};
```

I need get (inside Jenkins script pipeline) `key` value: `water`.
I can doing this by `readFile` function: [Jenkins Read a Specific Line of a File in Jenkinsfile with Groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58992842/6678345) and use `split` method.

**But I want to ask: is there any other solution to read value from JS file?**

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any out of the box solution for this but I can suggest using a regex for this. You can see the correct working of the regex on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rUvsLd/1).

```
(?<=key: ")(.*\n?)(?=",)
```

Use it like this:

```
def jsExport = readFile "<PathToFile>"
def regex = """(?<=key: ")(.*\n?)(?=",)"""
def result = (jsExport =~ regex)
echo "${result[0][0]}"
```

See a compileable example [here](http://tpcg.io/iafhZNOy).