# How to read line by line and get all subcontent using jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am writing a jenkins job to get all subcontent in a file.

the structure of this file looks like this:

```
 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,
 aa.aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa..aaa
 bb.bb.bbb.bb.bbbb.bbb:={orga=orga1, team=team1},
 ee.ee.bbb.ee.bbbb.eee:={orga=orga2, team=team3}
```

my goal is to get all subcontent which contains orga and team

I have tried

```
 def lines = new File(it.path).readLines()
                        def result = lines.findAll {it.contains(':={orga')}
                        println result.toString()
```

but I got Jenkins error through building.

any solutions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58992842/6509

Comment: that is not what I want

Comment: Sorry. I thought you wanted to read the lines of a text file

Comment: Try `def results = readFile(it.path).split("\n").findAll {it.contains(':={orga')}`