# Read .txt file from workspace groovy script in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jobs, workspace

I am new to Jenkins and to groovy scripting, I want to read a .txt file which is located in the workspace of one of the jobs. I am trying to do this way:

`myfile = Jenkins.instance.getJob('JobName').workspace.readFileFromWorkspace('file.txt');`

But leads to the following error:

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
>   hudson.FilePath.readFileFromWorkspace() is applicable for argument
>   types: (java.lang.String) values: [file.txt]

Comment: looks similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22917491/reading-file-from-workspace-in-jenkins-with-groovy-script

Comment: yes, I saw this post as well but the solutions proposed there did not solve my issue.

Comment: are you in jenkins-pipeline or usual jenkins groovy script? the class `hudson.FilePath` definitely has no method readFileFromWorkspace : http://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/FilePath.html

Comment: I working on usual groovy script.  As far as I am searching I am not finding any other way to read the file from workspace. My goal is to fetch the data from a file which contain the list of job names and parameters and to automate to trigger builds for these jobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
file = new File("${Jenkins.instance.getJob('JobName').workspace}/file.txt").text
```

Comment: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: workspace for class: org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling to make it work for the pom modules for a file in the workspace, in the 
Extended Choice Parameter. Here is my solution with the printlns:

```
import groovy.util.XmlSlurper
import java.util.Map
import jenkins.*
import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.*
import hudson.model.*    

try{
//get Jenkins instance
    def jenkins = Jenkins.instance
//get job Item
    def item = jenkins.getItemByFullName("The_JOB_NAME")
    println item
// get workspacePath for the job Item
    def workspacePath = jenkins.getWorkspaceFor (item)
    println workspacePath

    def file = new File(workspacePath.toString()+"\\pom.xml")
    def pomFile = new XmlSlurper().parse(file)
    def pomModules = pomFile.modules.children().join(",")
    return pomModules
} catch (Exception ex){
    println ex.message
}
```

Comment: I want to access/read all txt files (including sub dir of workspace as well) using groovy postbuild. How to do that?