# Reactive choice parameter to read from workspace file

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to implement active reactive choice parameter .
In reactive parameter basically I am hard coding the different options based on the active parameter

Below is the sample code

```
if (Target_Environment.equals("Dev01")) {
  return ["test_DEV"]
} else if (Target_Environment.equals("Dev02")) {
  return ["test3_DEV02","test2_DEV02"]
} else if (Target_Environment.equals("Dev03")) {
  return ["test3_DEV03"]
} else if (Target_Environment.equals("Sit03")) {
  return ["test3_SIT03"]
}else if (Target_Environment.equals("PPTE")) {
  return ["test3_PPTE"]
}  

else {
  return ["Please Select Target Environment"]
}
```

Instead hard coding the choices I want to read from a file in jenkins workspace and show the content as the choices , what would be an ideal way to go with that ?
The readFile is not working under return function

I am also trying with extended choice parameter but 
there I am passing a property file with filename however how can I pass the property file with if else condition

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading file from Workspace in Jenkins with Groovy script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22917491/reading-file-from-workspace-in-jenkins-with-groovy-script)

Comment: if I pass like below if (Target_Environment.equals("Dev01")) {
  return [ readFile Filename ]
} it doesnt work . I know how to read file but not sure how to pass the content in reactive choice parameter so its not a duplicate question

Comment: Have you found a way to do it ? I'm actually struggling with it right now and i'm affraid that you can't read from your workspace outside of the pipeline{} step

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if this is accurate. But I would expect that you can't read from the job workspace in a parameter like that because workspaces are created after a build (see below error message).

So if you create the job with no previous builds, there will be no workspace file to read from?

Whenever I have seen that parameter type used in the past, they usually read from a file on the server instead of the workspace.

---

***Error message from Jenkins jobs that have no previous builds:***

```
Error: no workspace

A project won't have any workspace until at least one build is performed.

Run a build to have Jenkins create a workspace.
```

Comment: I am fine with that , I can read from a file but even how can I do that in the return statement of a reactive choice parameter

Comment: Again, not 100% confident on the parameter as I haven't really used it but I would assume that something like the below may work for you:

```def list = []
def lines = file.readLines()

lines.each { String line ->
  list << line
}

return list```

This will return a list of things for the user to select from the file.

Another parameter you could use is the Extended Choice Parameter, it allows you to have the key/value be different. i.e. the user will see and select `Dev01` but the value used by Jenkins will be `test_DEV`.