# How to make Jenkins build passed or unstable depends on Serenity reports

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, serenity-bdd

How to make Jenkins build unstable if there are failure test cases in serenity report? I am using Jenkins declarative pipeline and publishing serenity reports using HTML publish plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22938132) for a related question.

You could either write your own script with exit codes as the author originally started with, or you could experiment with a plugin like top answer suggests.

Writing your own script will give you more control, but implementation might take less time using a plugin.

Comment: I am reading the serenity report in script block and taking decision accordingly. It worked for me like a charm. Thank you.