# Error .groovy file does not exist in workspace jenkins

Tags: jenkins, dsl, jenkins-groovy

I am testing a seed job in jenkins. So that, I am using dsl groovy script which call uploaded script from a **File location** parameter" in Jenkins configuration.

So I defined, **'src/test'** as  a **File location** parameter".

Then, I am calling it in the dsl step in the seed job using `readFileFromWorkspace` function.

```
 steps {
        dsl{
            text(readFile("src/test/UnixDSLJob.groovy"))
            ignoreExisting()
            removeAction('DELETE')
            removeViewAction('DELETE')
        }
    }
```

I got this error  :

> ERROR: (script, line 20) File src/test/UnixDSLJob.groovy does not
> exist in workspace

Then, I tried to test if there is no issue about the existance of the file using this command :

```
def file = readFileFromWorkspace("src/test/UnixDSLJob.groovy")
out.println(file)
```

I got the same error.

Or, I am sure that I upload the file before lunching the build.

I tried many solutions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22917491/reading-file-from-workspace-in-jenkins-with-groovy-script), like using `readFile` instead of`readFileFromWorkspace`, but I still having same issue.

Comment: Have you check the permissions whether the Jenkins user has permission to read the groovy file ?

Comment: @SouravAtta, I don't think that it's a permission problem because I did this task, two weeks ago. But, I forgot which command I used to read the .groovy file