# Is there a way to copy the content of a text file generated while Jenkins execution into Slack

Tags: jenkins, slack

I am new to *Jenkins*, exploring......

My problem statement is,
After *Jenkins* execution, a text file(`Output.txt`) is being generated into `Workspace`. The requirement is, I want to copy the contents of that `.txt` file and print it on *Slack* notification message.

I tried to create an "Execute Shell" inside that I wrote:

```
echo myVar=Property \> Something\\bin\\Release\\Output.txt
```

After that I used the `EnvInject` plugin, inside that in properties file path I have given the full path of `Output.txt`

In post-build build-action, I have selected *Slack* notification, in custom message I have written:

```
Data is- $myVar
Data is- $Property
```

Now When I am executing this Job I got *Slack* Notification, but didn't got the data of `Output.txt`.

I got this on *Slack*:

```
Data is- $myVar
Data is- $Property
```

What I am expecting, if `Output.txt` hold `hello world` then I want:

```
Data is - hello world
```

in *Slack* notification.

Comment: There is a plugin with simple usage of sending slack notifications via Jenkins...
https://plugins.jenkins.io/slack/

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. I know that but how to use the Contents of a text file that is in Jenkins Workspace into the Slack Notification plugin.

Comment: Do you want to attach it as a file or reading and writing to a message?

Comment: No, I do not want to attach the file with a slack notification. The Only thing I want is to print the content of Output.txt in Slack Notification. So, My Concern is about how to fetch the data from that Output.txt(Basically this file holds some data which is coming from API ) and print it into Slack (With the help of the plugin present in Post-build Action). Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0):

[upload file .txt](https://plugins.jenkins.io/slack/)

[Read .txt in jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22917491/reading-file-from-workspace-in-jenkins-with-groovy-script)

I think the best option is to read the .txt in jenkins, pass it to a variable and place it in the notification

Comment: Thanks for the Answer Alex, Would you please elaborate on how to read a text file from Jenkins Workspace and store it in a variable (As the Content inside Output.txt might be of Multiple Strings ).  And how to use that Variable in the Slack Notification Part. (As One Variable defined in One section bounded within the Section). Thanks in Advance!!