# Parse a huge JSON file

Tags: groovy

I have a very large JSON file (about a gigabyte) which I want to parse.

I tried the JsonSlurper, but it looks like it tries to load the whole file into memory which causes out of memory exception.

Here is a piece of code I have:

```
def parser = new JsonSlurper().setType(JsonParserType.CHARACTER_SOURCE);
def result = parser.parse(new File("equity_listing_full_201604160411.json"))

result.each{
println it.Listing.ID
}
```

And Json is something like this but much longer with more columns and rows

```
[
{"Listing": {"ID":"2013056","VERSION":"20160229:053120:000","NAME":"XXXXXX","C_ID":["1927445"],}},
{"Listing": {"ID":"2013057","VERSION":"20160229:053120:000","NAME":"XXXXXX","C_ID":["1927446"],}},
{"Listing": {"ID":"2013058","VERSION":"20160229:053120:000","NAME":"XXXXXX","C_ID":["1927447"],}}
]
```

I want to be able to read it row by row. I can probably just parse each row separately, but was thinking that there might be something for parsing as you read.

Comment: even though this is a very old question check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19522919/reading-json-object-from-txt-file-in-groovy

Answer (score 0):

Suggest using GSON by Google.
There is a streaming Parsing Option here: https://sites.google.com/site/gson/streaming