# Convert JSON to a map and pass JSOn data using variable

Tags: java, groovy

I want to parse this data using JSONSlurper and convert it into a map and then pass data using variable to a template.

```html
{ 
 "biodata": {
    "Ruby": {
      "Expertise": "web development",
      "EXperience": "5 years"
    },
    "Dylon": {
      "Expertise": "Java",
      "EXperience": "2 years"
    }
 }
}
```

Something like this:

```html
def myJson = fetchedJson

def experienceDylon = myJson.biodata.dylon.experience
```

How to achieve this using groovy?

Comment: http://groovy-lang.org/json.html

Comment: Thanks for the input . When I try to use this I get error :
def files = new File("C:/Users/.........................")
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
def object = jsonSlurper.parseText(files)

println "${object}"

assert object instanceof Map

Comment: It says : No signature of method: groovy.json.JsonSlurper.parseText() is applicable for argument types: (File) values: [C:\Users..........]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19533616/1759845

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this example:

```
import groovy.json.*

def file = new File("importData.json")
def myJson = new JsonSlurper().parse(file)

// note original JSON has 'EXperience'
def result =  myJson['biodata']['Dylon']['EXperience']
assert '2 years' == result
```