# Grails, access file from IDE and deployed WAR

Tags: java, maven, grails, groovy

I have Grails app, with a file (foo.bar) located at `{project_root}/src/groovy/resources/foo.bar`

I can access the file running on my local environment when I use:

```
this.getClass().getResource("/src/groovy/resources/foo.bar")
```

but not

```
this.getClass().getResource("foo.bar")
```

However, when I build a WAR using `grails war`, the file is copied to `WEB-INF/classes/resources/foo.bar`, and the code to access the file no longer works.

What's the correct place to put my file and also refer to it, so that it can be accessed the same way whether it's running in my local environment, or deployed in a WAR?

Thanks.

Comment: Try: `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("foo.bar")`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15389329/where-to-put-a-text-file-in-grails-and-how-to-get-the-path/15389537#15389537

Comment: Both are good links.  The getClassLoader() did the trick for me, AFTER I found out it doesn't work from a static method.